# Delete pictures from Facebook using CURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have a Facebook app, where I want to delete some pictures. I have the pictureid and access_token, and have tried every methods I have found on this site, but I get errors every time.

How can this be deleted with CURL?  I've started with this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete photo via Facebook API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6337969/cant-delete-photo-via-facebook-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does not permit applications to delete photos at all.

Comment: Hmm.. It's just one picture i want to delete, but if i change it to this it doesn't works:

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$picture_id.'/?access_token='.$access_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: Facebook still does not allow applications to delete photos, no matter what changes you make.

Comment: Ok, but its my own app who have created it?, is the answer still the same? :)

Comment: Applications ARE NOT allowed to delete photos, no matter who created the application.

Answer (score 4):

Applications can now delete Photos - created by that application.
I tried it with a photo uploaded to a page and deleted it with its id via the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

The curl url would be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$imageId.'?method=DELETE&access_token='.$token
```